# WCF Request throwing error when connecting with the certificate

Tags: wcf, soap, wcf-security, x509certificate2

Am trying to connect to saop service developed by a third party they use certificate authentication. I have the certificate and the WSDL file. I tested the request in Soap UI and postman by adding the certificate, everything is working fine there.
Now I tired to implement the same in .net core using WCF connected service. This time am getting the following error even though i added the certificate from StoreLocation.

```
HL7SOAPEndPointSvcSoapClient hL7SOAPEndPointSvcSoapClient = new HL7SOAPEndPointSvcSoapClient(EndpointConfiguration.HL7SOAPEndPointSvcSoap, "endpointtoconnect");
            hL7SOAPEndPointSvcSoapClient.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.CurrentUser, StoreName.Root, X509FindType.FindByIssuerName, "certificateiisuername");
            submitMessageRequest submitMessageRequest = new submitMessageRequest() { 
                Body = "meesege to sent"
            };
            hL7SOAPEndPointSvcSoapClient.OpenAsync();
            submitMessageResponse submitMessageResponse  = await hL7SOAPEndPointSvcSoapClient.submitMessageAsync(submitMessageRequest);
```

The error am getting is

```
The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was "".
```

Am not sure what is causing the issue because the same certificate is working fine in Soap UI and postman.

Comment: The certificate isn't there. Not sure why you are searching in Root store. The certificate should be in My store.

Comment: @crypt32 I installed the certificate in Root. thats why iam getting it from there. When debugging i can able to see the certificate in the "ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate"  property using quick watch.

Comment: And it has private key when you see in debugger? Either way, certificates with private keys should be installed in My store.

Comment: yes it has the private key when i checked with debugger. And also i tried as you mentioned installed the certificate in  My store but getting the same error.

Comment: Look at this, maybe it will help you:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/certauth?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution for the issue, We need to add the binding settings as follow. once i added the below setting it started working

```
            BasicHttpBinding b = new BasicHttpBinding();
            
            b.Security.Mode = System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
            b.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType=HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;
```

It might help other, Thanks